# Difference between void return type and no return type

Tags: dart

What is the difference between the two mentioned below

`void func1() { print('Hello World') }`

and

`func1() { print('Hello World') }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you omit types that cannot be inferred (whether return types, parameter types, etc.), the default type is `dynamic`.

You can verify this yourself by going to https://dartpad.dartlang.org/ , entering a function with no return type:

```dart
func1() { print('Hello World'); }
```

and clicking on it.  DartPad's Documentation pane will tell that `func1` has a return type of `dynamic`.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a function void, you're explicitly declaring that it is intended to return no arguments, and it will therefore generate a compile error if you put e.g. a "return 0" into it.

Leaving out the void you're accepting default behavior.

Comment: is the default behaviour to return void, or is it something else?

Comment: default is dynamic I believe